# How can I use two TP4056 with four Li-ion batteries, but single load?

Tags: battery-charging

Need to connect and charge two Li-ion batteries in series.
I'm not sure if it is possible to connect and use two Li-ion batteries and TP4056 like this. Are they going to be balanced? Do they need to?

[image]

Comment: No, you can't do that. Probably IN- and BAT- are connected together. Now look at your 5 V in. It will connect to BAT- of the top board and put +5 V on the BAT+ of the lower board.

Comment: That's why i connected top li ion between 10V and 5V, and the last one between 5V and 0. So top bat should be ok (?)

Comment: No. It's just a very bad solution. You can see in Tony's answer that R2, for example, is between the BAT- and IN-. (It's probably a low value for current sensing.) If you connect BAT- to BAT+ of the lower board you will completely mess this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Thus your problem now looks like this.
[image]

"No Way, Jose".

**Yes they need to be balanced** to prevent accelerated aging from mismatch charge imbalance with high current and deep discharges.

- It is analogous to runaway series incandescent lightbulbs ( where the faster weaker bulb achieves near full brightness and the other bulb stays cool.
- Another example is like mismatched-Vf shunt LEDs sharing current. If one LED cannot support the current of 2 or more in parallel, one can burn out open cct as thermal runaway lowers the Vf of the hotter LED thus drawing more current.

  There is a better chance of extending end-of-life to achieve the max rated charge cycles if they are balanced or much lower if they are not!